# how do I read a regex separated by a new line

Tags: regex, perl

How do I read a URL which is split over two lines using regex in Perl?

```
[REQ-URL]: http://hostname:8080/guiderest?
customerId=cisco&code=news&guide=MostPopular&attrFilter=BlogFlag:true&v=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my ($url) = $text =~ /( http [\S\r\n]+ )/x;
$url =~ tr|\r\n||d;
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. However this regex doesnt seem to work .

Comment: `(my $url = $text) =~ s/(^\[(.+?)\]:\s|\r|\n)//g;`.

Comment: Maybe we are misunderstanding your input data: http://codepad.org/bgxtCK9S and http://codepad.org/cKycazJb.

Comment: @Chris : I apologize for creating a confusion, however your regex is absolutely working fine but problem is I have this data logged in 100' of pages and some of the URL's are 2 lines long while others are 3 lines long. So regex messes up I guess .

Comment: @mpapec : I apologize for creating a confusion, however your regex is absolutely working fine but problem is I have this data logged in 100' of pages and some of the URL's are 2 lines long while others are 3 lines long. So regex messes up I guess .

Comment: Is there any indication of where the URL ends i.e. double newline. Otherwise it may be difficult to decifer where the URL should end. i.e. http://codepad.org/bZMnGkJ4.

Comment: @user2457969 post more lines of relevant input